# I want one of the String member variables in my Spring Boot Java @Entity model class to show up as an actual JSON object when sent to the client side

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want one of the String member variables in my Spring Boot Java @Entity model class to show up as an actual JSON object when sent to the client side, but I am not sure how this is possible

I have this @Entity class in Spring Boot :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {

    @JsonProperty
    private String value
}
```

That "value" in the class A is supposed to be a JSON object, but I had to keep it in string type or it won't save into the DB by JPA.

When the controller returns this model object to the client side, the "value" in the JSON string will show up as a full string instead of a JSON struct.

i.e.

This shows up

```
{
  "value": "{\"another_value\":\"1234\"}"
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "value": {"another_value":"1234"}
}
```

Is there some easy way to annotate the "value" in my class A to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What about defining a custom @JsonGetter for `getValue()` instead of using the one that Lombok is generating. In that getter, instead of returning `String`, have it return `JsonNode` by parsing the JSON string with `new ObjectMapper().readTree(value);`. Seems like that could work?

Comment: Yea @nickb , using JsonGetter does work, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear it. Not sure why somebody came along an hour later to give the exact same recommendation as an answer using GSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a custom Getter for converting it while de-serializing. I am using google gson for deserializing.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {

    @JsonProperty
    private String value;

    @JsonGetter("value")
    public HashMap getValueAsJson(){
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, HashMap.class);
    }
}
```